# GridLayout not responsive with ImageView

Tags: android, android-gridlayout

I am using `android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout` to make a grid of ImageViews of 3x3. I wanted it to be responsive for all the screens.
Below is my layout.xml. But no image is visible if I am using `columnWeight` and `app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"` .But if I am giving solid `width` and `height` then its working.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/aodText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/activity_of_day"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.FontPath"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/aodText"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
        app:cardElevation="2dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:padding="10dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/refresh"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_name" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/shareColoredKolam"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_facebook" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/colorLayout"
                android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout">

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/colorKolamCard"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
                    app:cardElevation="2dp"
                    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
                    app:contentPadding="16dp">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
                        android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:columnCount="3"
                        app:rowCount="3">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/r1c1"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="84dp"
                            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                            android:scaleType="fitXY"
                            android:src="@drawable/a270"
                            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                            app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/r1c2"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="84dp"
                            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                            android:scaleType="fitXY"
                            android:src="@drawable/c0"
                            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                            app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/r1c3"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="84dp"
                            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                            android:scaleType="fitXY"
                            android:src="@drawable/a0"
                            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                            app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/r2c1"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="84dp"
                            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                            android:scaleType="fitXY"
                            android:src="@drawable/c270"
                            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                            app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/r2c2"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="84dp"
                            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                            android:scaleType="fitXY"
                            android:src="@drawable/e90"
                            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                            app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/r2c3"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="84dp"
                            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                            android:scaleType="fitXY"
                            android:src="@drawable/c90"
                            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                            app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/r3c1"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="84dp"
                            android:scaleType="fitXY"
                            android:src="@drawable/a180"
                            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                            app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/r3c2"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="84dp"
                            android:scaleType="fitXY"
                            android:src="@drawable/c180"
                            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                            app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/r3c3"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="84dp"
                            android:scaleType="fitXY"
                            android:src="@drawable/a90"
                            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                            app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal" />
                    </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/colorLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                app:cardCornerRadius="1dp"
                app:cardElevation="3dp">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="16dp">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:columnCount="10"
                        app:rowCount="2">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/redBtn"
                            android:layout_width="22dp"
                            android:layout_height="22dp"
                            android:layout_margin="1dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/rounded_button" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/pinkBtn"
                            android:layout_width="22dp"
                            android:layout_height="22dp"
                            android:layout_margin="1dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/rounded_button" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/purpleBtn"
                            android:layout_width="22dp"
                            android:layout_height="22dp"
                            android:layout_margin="1dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/rounded_button" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/deepPurpleBtn"
                            android:layout_width="22dp"
                            android:layout_height="22dp"
                            android:layout_margin="1dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/rounded_button" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/indigoBtn"
                            android:layout_width="22dp"
                            android:layout_height="22dp"
                            android:layout_margin="1dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/rounded_button" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/blueBtn"
                            android:layout_width="22dp"
                            android:layout_height="22dp"
                            android:layout_margin="1dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/rounded_button" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/lightBlueBtn"
                            android:layout_width="22dp"
                            android:layout_height="22dp"
                            android:layout_margin="1dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/rounded_button" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/cyanBtn"
                            android:layout_width="22dp"
                            android:layout_height="22dp"
                            android:layout_margin="1dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/rounded_button" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/tealBtn"
                            android:layout_width="22dp"
                            android:layout_height="22dp"
                            android:layout_margin="1dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/rounded_button" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/greenBtn"
                            android:layout_width="22dp"
                            android:layout_height="22dp"
                            android:layout_margin="1dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/rounded_button" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/lightGreenBtn"
                            android:layout_width="22dp"
                            android:layout_height="22dp"
                            android:layout_margin="1dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/rounded_button" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/limeBtn"
                            android:layout_width="22dp"
                            android:layout_height="22dp"
                            android:layout_margin="1dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/rounded_button" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/yellowBtn"
                            android:layout_width="22dp"
                            android:layout_height="22dp"
                            android:layout_margin="1dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/rounded_button" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/amberBtn"
                            android:layout_width="22dp"
                            android:layout_height="22dp"
                            android:layout_margin="1dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/rounded_button" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/orangeBtn"
                            android:layout_width="22dp"
                            android:layout_height="22dp"
                            android:layout_margin="1dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/rounded_button" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/deepOrangeBtn"
                            android:layout_width="22dp"
                            android:layout_height="22dp"
                            android:layout_margin="1dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/rounded_button" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/brownBtn"
                            android:layout_width="22dp"
                            android:layout_height="22dp"
                            android:layout_margin="1dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/rounded_button" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/blueGreyBtn"
                            android:layout_width="22dp"
                            android:layout_height="22dp"
                            android:layout_margin="1dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/rounded_button" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/greyBtn"
                            android:layout_width="22dp"
                            android:layout_height="22dp"
                            android:layout_margin="1dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/rounded_button" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/whiteBtn"
                            android:layout_width="22dp"
                            android:layout_height="22dp"
                            android:layout_margin="1dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/rounded_button" />

                    </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
                </RelativeLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <!--<me.zhanghai.android.materialprogressbar.MaterialProgressBar-->
            <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
            <!--android:id="@+id/pdfProgressBar"-->
            <!--android:layout_centerInParent="true"-->
            <!--style="@style/Widget.MaterialProgressBar.ProgressBar.Large"-->
            <!--android:indeterminate="true"-->
            <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content" />-->

            <!--<com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView-->
            <!--android:id="@+id/kodpdfView"-->
            <!--android:visibility="gone"-->
            <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
            <!--android:layout_height="match_parent" />-->
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the output:

[image]

**Why am I not able to see images ?**

Comment: Try to give width to Grid layout `android:layout_width="match_parent"`

Comment: didnt work after making it to `match_parent`. Same result

Comment: I tried your code and give width to Grid layout `android:layout_width="match_parent"` and its working.

Comment: Yeah I changed parent width to `match_parent` then it worked. But now there is a gap coming in between the images. How can I remove those gap ?

Comment: will you share your whole xml and image??

Comment: I fixed it by adding `scaleType=fitXY`. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to give width to Grid layout `android:layout_width="match_parent"`
and imageview to `scaleType=fitXY`